# "System.ArgumentException: 'The path is not of a legal form." Facing this error

Tags: forms, exception, path, arguments, system

The system is not showing any error but repeatedly running the update method shows this problem.  But when I did the same process while inserting there was no problem.

I was working on a Crud operation in windows form and I was able to do insert and delete successfully.  But during update I managed to load the data in the same process of insert but during insert I did not face problem with image data but during update problem